# VTK: How to display only a particular range of data

Tags: vtk, post-processing, paraview

I have a vtk file which contains density values for each cell. By default, paraview displays all the density range. However, I would like to view density data only within a particular range and its corresponding cells only.

Is it possible to view only the cells, which fall in the particular range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way:

1. view-> selection inspector
   In the selection inspector,
2. current object: (select the grid you want to visualize)
3. selection Type: Threshold
4. Field Type: CELL
5. scalars: (select the cell scalar to visualize, in my case: density)
6. Add Thresholds -> Lower: (set your value) Upper: (set your value)
7. Display style->Cell Label tab
                  Visible;
                 Label Mode: (select the cell scalar to visualize, in my case: density)

Now you are done!

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly apply the "Threshold" filter to remove cells from the dataset that are beyond your selected range and just visualize the remaining ones.